# Question about subnetting with switch

Tags: routing, switch, ethernet, subnet

I have a setup which includes desktop pc, server pc(would also act as router), raspberry pi and ethernet switch (and possibly other devices if I get new switch). I would like to know if this configuration is possible. My server and desktop pc have only one network interface controllers.

So my question is: Is it possible to connect all the devices to switch and plug the switch to wall socket and server would route with virtual interfaces between networks with only one physical interface?

I have made illustration of my setup to clarify.
[image]

Computers in subnet for example 192.168.1.x (mask 255.255.255.0) would have static IPs and server(router) computer's public virtual interface would get IP with DHCP.

Would this kind of setup work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would, sort of, but for a few £/$/€ you could buy a second network card for your server/router and do it right.

In either case, though, you will need to set the server/router as the default gateway for your other devices, and MASQUERADE (SNAT) all traffic heading out from your server/router to the rest of the world.